# How to add false positive using XSLT file in OWASP ZAP scan in Azure DevOps?

Tags: security, azure-devops, owasp, zap, penetration-testing

I have integrated OWASP ZAP into my Azure Pipeline. After the completion of the build, the report I am getting also contains some false positive issues (an issue that isn't feasible for my application).

1. I am using  **"OWASPToNUnit3.XSLT"** file.

Is there any way through which I can put some condition/filter to ignore the false positive?

Answer (score 1):

We have a FAQ for handling false positived in ZAP: https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/how-do-i-handle-a-false-positive/

I dont know anything about that file so cant advice on that.